# Play sound sequentially with no delay between the parts [Android]

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

In my Android application I want to play sequentially some sound that was divided to parts before. Each part is a .wave file with 2-3 seconds length.

I do perform that successfully, but I have a noticeable delay between those parts.

My code looks now like that -

```
localMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer[3];
localMediaPlayer[0] = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound_1);
localMediaPlayer[1] = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound_2);
localMediaPlayer[2] = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound_3);
```

---

```
public void onClick_localBtn(View v){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Play Local Sound", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    localMediaPlayer[0].start();
    localMediaPlayer[0].setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        localMediaPlayer[1].start();
        }
        });
    localMediaPlayer[1].setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            localMediaPlayer[2].start();
        }
    });
}
```

How can I improve my code that those parts will play smooth and with no delay, like if it were a 1 file sound?

Thanks.

Comment: it will obviously cause a slight period to load and play that other clip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start playing your (N)th media player, call `prepareAsync()` on your (N+1)th media player:

```
localMediaPlayer[0].start();
localMediaPlayer[1].prepareAsync();
    localMediaPlayer[0].setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        localMediaPlayer[1].start();
        localMediaPlayer[2].prepareAsync();
        }
        });
    localMediaPlayer[1].setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            localMediaPlayer[2].start();
        }
    });
```

**Edit**

Based on your update and your comment, perhaps a better way would to be time the playing of the next media player according to the duration of the previous player minus some delta:

```
private static final int DURATION_DELTA = 1000;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

public void playMediaPlayer(final int index) {
   if (index >= localMediaPlayer.length || localMediaPlayer[index] == null)
       return;


   localMediaPlayer[index].start();
   final int duration = localMediaPlayer[index].getDuration();

   mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

       @Override
       public void run() {
           playMediaPlayer(index + 1);
       }
   }, duration - DURATION_DELTA);
}
```

This code will basically play a media player, then schedule playing the next media player approx 1 second before the next media player ends. It's a bit "hacky", but you can play around with it (the value for DURATION_DELTA) until you get the best results.

Comment: Gil, in that case I got an error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick`

Comment: try replacing the prepareAsync() calls with prepare()

Comment: As I learned now from the [MediaPlayer documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) in my case, because I use a create() method, my localMediaPlayer[] is already in the prepared state. I updated the question with rest of code. Have you any other thoughts? It must be some way to solve this, because the delay is very noticeable right now. Thanks Gil!

Comment: Wow, good idea. It's a good implementation for a few parts, although in multi-part audio it's running over. Close enough to solution so I'll mark it as solved. Thanks Gil!